# NodeJS / NPM not found via SSH although installed in WHM

Tags: node.js, ssh, whm, server-administration

first time poster -- searched but couldn't find anyone with quite this issue.

Running EC2 instance with current WHM.  Trying to get npm to work, but for some reason simply cannot.  First was finding that NodeJS was not installed on the server.  I went to WHM > Software > Additional and installed NodeJS16.  I restarted Apache, that didn't seem to do the trick, so then tried a Graceful Reboot for good measure.

When I go to SSH and try node -v, I get command not found.  Same with npm -v.

I tried going to /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin which holds both node and npm files, but even with this I get:

[root@srv bin]# node -v
-bash: node: command not found
[root@srv bin]# npm -v
-bash: npm: command not found

Have I missed a step following install?  WHM shows the package is installed.

Thanks,
TW